# Radeon Driver Help!

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, gpu

So after 3 days of trying to figure out why my computer wasn't letting me boot off anything other than windows, I figured out why.

My Graphics Card wasn't letting me.

I took it out and it let me install Ubuntu. Now, I don't want to continue running on my Integrated Graphics Card. I want to pop my GPU back in (Which is a Radeon R7 370) and play some games. Where can I find the drivers available for the GPU and install them on linux?

Answer (score 1):

have you checked here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD  try searching a little before posting in the forums...

Answer (score 1):

3rd party drivers can be tricky with Ubuntu, but I have had quite a bit of success.

NOTE: At least in my case, if you do a system update (one that requires authorization) you'll have to re-install the drivers. Pain in the butt, but it could be worse.

[Check this link out](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)